# SU(2) invariant structures and the Frobenius Schur indicator

Tags: lie-groups, symmetric-matrices, bilinear-form, unitary-matrices, skew-symmetric-matrices

For $SU(2)$, the fundamental representation is a quaternionic representation. Which means there is a preserved skew symmetric form, written as a matrix:

$$
\varepsilon = \left(\begin{array}{cc} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0\end{array}\right)
$$
i.e. for any element $U \in SU(2)$
$$
\quad U^T \varepsilon \>U = \varepsilon
$$

However there is simultaneously a symmetric invariant bi-linear form:

$$
g = \left(\begin{array}{cc} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{array}\right)
$$
i.e. for any element $U \in SU(2)$
$$
\quad U^\dagger g \>U = g
$$

How can there be simultaneously two invariant bi-linear forms given the well known theorems regarding the [Frobenius-Schur indicator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius%E2%80%93Schur_indicator)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've realized this question only arises from forgetting a minor detail: the answer to this is that the $g$ is not bilinear, it is sesquilinear, for which the Frobenius-Schur indicator tells us nothing about. Thus having both is fine.